# Solving this population (growth) DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

At every point in time, a mass $n(t)$ enters the population with age zero. Both time $t$ and age $a$ are continuous, and $F(a, t)$ denotes the mass of people with age at or below $a$ at time $t$. People die at rate $e(a)$.

**I am interested in computing $\partial_t F(a, t)$, given initial $F(a, 0)$**

**My approach** The mass of people at or below $a$ in $t+\Delta$ is given by those who are below $a$ today, minus those who die, plus those who get born.

$$ F(a+\Delta, t+\Delta) = F(a, t) - \int_0^a \Delta e(a)\partial_a F(a', t)da' + \Delta n(t) $$

Moving $F(a,t)$ to the left-hand-side, dividing by $\Delta$, and letting $\Delta\to0$:

$$ (\partial_a + \partial_t) F(a, t) = - \int_0^a e(a)\partial_a F(a', t)da' + n(t) $$

I was hoping for something more explicit. Is there something else I can do?